# What is the way to update the option values of a select control from the value emitted by another control?

Tags: angular, angular-formly

In a form similar to this

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({});
  modela!: any;
  fieldsa: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'field1',
      type: 'select',
      props: {
        label: 'Field1',
        options: this.someService.getData(),
        change: (field) => {
          field.formControl?.valueChanges.subscribe({
            next: (value) => {},
          });
        },
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'field2',
      type: 'select',
      props: {
        label: 'Field2',
        options: [],
      },
    },
  ];
```

How to get the option values of the keyed field field2 to update based on the emitted value of field1?

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this problem is by implementing cascading dropdown fields. The target control subscribes to the `onInit` hook. Here, through `field`, the value of the `options` property is updated by the value obtained from a call to a service with the value of the other control selected as an argument.

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({});
model!: { field1: ""; field2: "" };
fieldsa: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
  {
    key: "field1",
    type: "select",
    props: {
      label: "Field 1",
      options: this.someService.getField1Data(),
    },
  },
  {
    key: "field2",
    type: "select",
    props: {
      label: "Field 2",
      options: [],
    },
    hooks: {
      onInit: (field) => {
        field.props!.options = field.form?.valueChanges.pipe(
          switchMap((value) => this.someService.getField2Data(value))
        );
      },
    },
  },
];
```

You can see an example in this post https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-implement-cascading-dropdown-fields-with-angular-formly